# Куда делся assemblycsharp.dll

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я видел много людей пишущих мобильные игры на unity c#, но проблема в том что когда я распаковывал apk файл, Я не обнаруживал файл assemblycshap.dll, а лишь classes.dex. Мне нужно найти файлы c# скриптов, а не classes.dex, а так же узнать откуда они вообще там взялись

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: apk - э то скомпилированный нативный код, никаких C# скриптов вы там не найдете.

Comment: А где тогда мне искать логику игры? В classes.dex?